# What is so special about Arnold's Trivium?

Tags: education

I have read from [*Experimental Mathematics* by V. I. Arnold](https://books.google.com/books?id=KAkpCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&dq=adriana+ortiz+vladimir+arnold) that if someone wants to study with Vladimir Arnold, they must solve [Arnold's Trivium](http://hans.math.upenn.edu/Arnold/Arnold-Trivium-1991.pdf) first in order to "understand mathematics". Arnold himself had said that solving the Trivium was a way to truly understand mathematics.

Why? What does Arnold mean with "truly understand mathematics"?

Comment: It might help if you were to tell us what the Trivium is.

Comment: After a short look into the paper, it mainly seems to consist of a set of tasks. I guess the point of those tasks is not to *gain* mathematical understanding, but to to *test* mathematical understanding. That is, it's not that you need to have completed those tasks to obtain mathematical understanding, but that by being able to solve those tasks, you demonstrate understanding of mathematics.

Comment: Do you have any source for these quotes, or paraphrases? Particularly the claim you're attributing to Arnold? I think you're misrepresenting Arnold's purpose in constructing this collection of problems.

Comment: https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=KAkpCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=adriana+ortiz+vladimir+arnold&source=bl&ots=tefxani0XC&sig=iZwC7BMlVEo_WiChr1l2oxuFKwk&hl=es-419&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=adriana%20ortiz%20vladimir%20arnold&f=false

Comment: In p.9, he says that Adriana Ortiz "started making sense of mathematics"

Answer (score 19):

(*Too long for a comment*.)  Quoting author's motivation from the source (page 2 of the linked pdf):

> In  Feynman's  words,  these students  understand  nothing,  but  never  ask  questions, so  that  they
>   appear  to understand  everything. [...] ***The  students  reach  a  state of  "self-propagating  pseudo-education"  and  can teach  future
>   generations in  the same way***.  But  all  this  activity  is completely  senseless,  and  in  fact  our  output  of
>   specialists is to  a  significant  extent a fraud,  an  illusion  and  a sham:  ***these so-called specialists are not
>   in  a position  to  solve  the  simplest  problems,  and  do  not  possess the  rudiments  of  their  trade***.
>
> Thus, ***to put  an end to  this spurious enhancement of  the results, we  must  specify  not  a  list  of
>   theorems, but  a collection of problems  which students should be able to solve***.  [...] The  compilation  of  model  problems  is  a laborious job,  but  I think  it  must  be  done.  ***As  an  attempt
>   I  give  below  a list  of  one hundred  problems  forming  a mathematical  minimum  for  a physics  student***.

Answer (score 13):

There's nothing inherently special about the problems (and they're not even, say, math-contest-style problems); they're just intended to be reasonably comprehensive (with respect to an undergrad math education) and demonstrate the virtues of a written rather than oral examination. There's nothing there that anyone with a undergrad math degree should have any problem with, possibly modulo looking up a couple of specific formulas. He published a note after the problem set comparing it to other such examinations, if that's helpful to you.

That having been said, the subjects chosen aren't what I would expect. There's a lot of involved calculation, including some questions on numeric approximations. There are pages and pages and pages of questions about differential equations; in fact, the questions are heavily skewed to applied math in general. There are a couple of desultory questions about group theory and probability at the end, but that's about it; the rest is real and complex analysis (including a bunch of computations of specific integrals) and dozens of questions about differential equations. There's nothing about set theory, ring theory, commutative algebra, Galois theory, topology (beyond one question about Betti numbers and a couple about Riemann surfaces), Lie algebras (Problems #89 and #90 don't count), representation theory, any group theory that one wouldn't get in a physics class, etc. That would make more sense if Arnol'd was using it as a way to weed out prospective grad students working specifically under him, but it focuses on an extraordinarily narrow and applied curriculum. It doesn't strike me as a great way of demonstrating mathematical understanding.

Comment: "There's nothing inherently special about the problems (and they're not even, say, math-contest-style problems)" This might be your opinion but then you should be aware that Arnol'd and quite a few other people strongly disagree with it (but you are right that the problems are not math-contest-style... in fact they are much more interesting than that).

Comment: I think a key point which @dxiv highlights is that Arnold saw it as a "list of one hundred problems forming a mathematical minimum for a physics student'. As such, it is no surprise that it focuses on a narrow and applied curriculum.

Comment: @James: Sure. I just wouldn't hold it up as an exemplar of what a _math_ undergrad should know.

Comment: I agree - and, based on the quote I gave, I would guess Arnold does as well.

Comment: @Did: If you strongly disagree, then show what's interesting about them. To take a couple at random: #13 is unremakrable;  #89 and #90 really want to be questions about Lie algebras but aren't (and one can just compute them directly); #46 is the tedious sort of problem that's best solved by looking up a table of such things (though this particular one is easy enough, and it's not a great question to discuss the Riemann mapping theorem) ; #50 is the sort of real-integral-by-Cauchy's-theorem question that's on every final exam in intro complex analysis; and so on.

Comment: "There's nothing there that anyone with a undergrad math degree should have any problem with": I strongly suspect that Arnold expected _freshmen_ physics students to be able to solve those problems, not the older ones.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: The anecdote about Adriana Ortiz above suggests that it was designed for third- or fourth-year undergrads wanting to work with Arnol'd. None of the problems there are particularly difficult or require a huge amount of mathematical background, but I wouldn't expect freshman physics students to know anything about, say, Betti numbers.